# Number of functions from set $A$ to set $B$ in which the sum of the function values is even

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3,\ldots, 12\}, B = \{101, 102,\ldots, 106\}$, number of functions defined from $A$ to $B$ such that $f(1) + f(2) + \ldots + f(12)$ is even is

(A) $6^{12}$

(B) $3.6^{11}$

(C) $6^{11}$

(D) $3^{12} – 1$

My approach number of elements in set $A$ is $n(A)=12$ and number of elements in set $B$ is $n(B)=6$.

Total number of functions $= 6^{12}$

My assumption is that half of the sum is even and half is odd. Therefore, number of function is $3.6^{11}$, but not sure of my method.

Comment: You should use \cdot for the multiplication dot instead of a period.  $3.6^{11}$ looks to me like $(3.6)^{11}$ with the $3.6$ a decimal number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that there are $6^{11}$ functions $g:\left\{ 1,\dots,11\right\} \to B$.

If $g$ is such a function then there are $3$ ways to construct a
function $f:\left\{ 1,\dots,11,12\right\} \to B$ such that $f\left(i\right)=g\left(i\right)$
for every $i\in\left\{ 1,\dots,11\right\} $ and $\sum_{k=1}^{12}f\left(k\right)$
is even.

(If $\sum_{k=1}^{11}g\left(k\right)$ is even then it is necessary and sufficient to go for  $f(12)\in\{102,104,106\}$ and if $\sum_{k=1}^{11}g\left(k\right)$ is odd then it is necessary and sufficient to go for  $f(12)\in\{101,103,105\}$. So in both cases $3$ possibilities)

So there are $3\cdot6^{11}$ such functions in total.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a dice. The outcomes where the sum of the one dice is even are 3 and the outcomes where the sum of the dice is odd are 3.

For $n$ dice let's assume that there are $m$ outcomes where the sum is even and $m$ outcomes where the sum is odd. So for $n+1$ dice there are $3*m$ outcomes where the sum is even and $3*m$ outcomes where the sum is odd.

So by induction we have that the number of outcomes where the sum of $k$ dice is even and the number of outcomes where the sum is odd are equal for every $k\in N$.

This is practically the same as your problem so the answer is $3*6^{11}$ as you correctly said in your question.

Note: $dice_1=3,dice_2=4$ is counted as a different outcome than $dice_1=4,dice_2=3$. I used dice and this way to demonstrate the solution because that's how I thought it. The principle is the same for the problem you are stating